# Unable to install APK in Unity

Tags: android, game-engine, unity-game-engine

I have a project aka Game_1 which I replicated from previous project aka Game_0. I am trying to install apk of Game_1 in my device but I get error "unable to install apk".

My device already contains an APK of Game_0. When I uninstall APK of Game_0, I can install Game_1 apk.

Both apk have different product name and different package names. They both are build by same keystone file. My unity version is 5.3.3 and I have also tried on 5.4.1 but same error pop ups.

I have also made sure that install location is automatic in player setting. I was continuing the same process from last 6 months and everything was going along very nicely. Now when I do the same stuff, I am getting installation error.

Can anyone tell me if there is some hidden file which makes both APK's identical for device to install ?

Error Msg is something like this

```
UnityException: Unable to install APK!
Installation failed. See the Console for details.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuildPointToConsole (System.String title, System.String message)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.PublishPackage.UploadAndStartPlayer (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context, Boolean retryUpload)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.PublishPackage.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (BuildPostProcessArgs args)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, Int32 width, Int32 height, System.String downloadWebplayerUrl, System.String manualDownloadWebplayerUrl, BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:176)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
Installation failed with the following output:
[  0%] /data/local/tmp/Package.apk
[  0%] /data/local/tmp/Package.apk
```